# What is the boundary of the solid torus $\mathbb D^2 \times \mathbb S^1$? And extend it to higher dimension.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

We know that the boundary of the 3-manifold solid torus $\mathbb D^2 \times \mathbb S^1$ is $\mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1$.

Now the question is as follows:

> > How does this generalize to dimensions larger than 3?

Can someone please let me know what does this question means? Does it say that extend it for higher genus?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, higher dimension is not the same thing as higher genus. The genus of a surface refers to how many "handles" it has, while the dimension is for which $n$ is it locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (and do not even use the word "surface" unless $n=2$.)

The solid torus $\mathbb{D}^2\times \mathbb{S}^1$ is a 3-dimensional manifold, and its boundary the torus $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$ is 2-dimensional.

A higher dimensional analogue of this question would be "what is the boundary of $\mathbb{D}^3\times \mathbb{S}^2$? And the answer would be $\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{S}^2.$

Or maybe just one dimension higher, "what is the boundary of $\mathbb{D}^3\times \mathbb{S}^1$? Answer: $\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{S}^1.$

Or what is the boundary of $\mathbb{D}^2\times (\mathbb{S}^1)^{n-1}$? Answer: $\mathbb{S}^1)^n$, sometimes called the $n$-dimensional torus or $n$-torus (but don't confuse it with the $n$-handled torus).

More generally the boundary of $\mathbb{D}^{m+1}\times \mathbb{S}^n$ is $\mathbb{S}^{m}\times \mathbb{S}^n.$

Even *more* generally, we have for any manifolds with boundary $X$ and $Y$,

$$\partial(X\times Y)=\partial X\times Y\cup X\times\partial Y.$$

Comment: Many thanks for your knowledgeable answer! Can you please let me what $\mathbb{D}^3\times \mathbb{S}^2$ is called?

Comment: @user513784 I do not know any name for this manifold. I would simply call it $\mathbb{D}^3\times\mathbb{S}^2$.

Comment: Maybe it could be called a 2-handle. Or a thickened 2-sphere.

Comment: Many thanks! I googled it and is written it is a 5-manifold. Maybe it's boundary is the 4-manifold $\mathbb D^2 \times \mathbb S^2$?

Comment: @user513784 no, the boundary of $\mathbb{D}^3\times\mathbb{S}^2$ is $\mathbb{S}^2\times\mathbb{S}^2.$ I mentioned this in my answer.

Comment: Many thanks! Yes I see. I just was a bit curious!

Comment: @ziggurism Hi, i interested in this particular subject too. Can you recommend to me some reference where i can learn this ? Thanks.

Comment: A good textbook for learning smooth manifold is Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by John Lee, who also sometimes answers questions about manifolds on this website.

Comment: @ziggurism I mean not about smooth manifold (i'm using Lee's too btw). I looking for sth more like diff top, such as cobordism, handles, surgery etc.

Comment: @Sou for handlebodies and surgery and cobordism groups of smooth spheres, stuff like that, the textbook I used was by Kosinski. It's not as awesome as Lee, but there aren't many textbooks in this area so you gotta take what you can get.

Comment: @ziggurism Thank you. I'll look at it.